# xjc error: "Two declarations cause a collision" on valid .xsd

Tags: java, validation, xjc

I've got a valid .xsd as API description. Here it is (w/o redundant code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="String">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ErrorType">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Type">          
                <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="String" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ErrorTypeType">
        <xsd:attribute name="Code" type="String" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="String" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

It is validated by http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/

But `xjc MySchema.xsd` raises the following error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 17 of file:/C:/Users/dev05/Downloads/MySchema.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 10 of file:/C:/Users/dev05/Downloads/MySchema.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

Should I ask API creators to change it (that is quite hard) or there are some workarounds to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3):

To resolve that I add bindings file:

**bindings.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true">
        <xjc:serializable />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Common.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ErrorTypeType']">
               <jaxb:class name="ErrorTypeType1"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And shell command will be:

```
xjc -b bindings.xml -extension MySchema.xsd
```